# In R, how do I locally shuffle a vector's elements

Tags: r, sample

I have the following vector in R. Think of them as a vector of numbers.

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,...100)
```

I want to randomize this vector "locally" based on some input number the "locality factor". For example if the locality factor is 3, then the first 3 elements are taken and randomized followed by the next 3 elements and so on. Is there an efficient way to do this? I know if I use sample, it would jumble up the whole array.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### General solution:

Edit: As @MatthewLundberg comments, the issue I pointed out with "repeating numbers in x" can be easily overcome by working on `seq_along(x)`, which would mean the resulting values will be indices. So, it'd be like so:

```
k <- 3
x <- c(2,2,1, 1,3,4, 4,6,5, 3)
x.s <- seq_along(x)
y <- sample(x.s)
x[unlist(split(y, (match(y, x.s)-1) %/% k), use.names = FALSE)]
# [1] 2 2 1 3 4 1 4 5 6 3
```

---

#### Old answer:

The bottleneck here is the amount of calls to function `sample`. And as long as your numbers don't repeat, I think you can do this with just one call to `sample` in this manner:

```
k <- 3
x <- 1:20
y <- sample(x)
unlist(split(y, (match(y,x)-1) %/% k), use.names = FALSE)
# [1]  1  3  2  5  6  4  8  9  7 12 10 11 13 14 15 17 16 18 19 20
```

---

To put everything together in a function (I like the name `scramble` from @Roland's):

```
scramble <- function(x, k=3) {
    x.s <- seq_along(x)
    y.s <- sample(x.s)
    idx <- unlist(split(y.s, (match(y.s, x.s)-1) %/% k), use.names = FALSE)
    x[idx]
}

scramble(x, 3)
# [1] 2 1 2 3 4 1 5 4 6 3
scramble(x, 3)
# [1] 1 2 2 1 4 3 6 5 4 3
```

---

To reduce the answer (and get it faster) even more, following @flodel's comment:

```
scramble <- function(x, k=3L) {
    x.s <- seq_along(x)
    y.s <- sample(x.s)
    x[unlist(split(x.s[y.s], (y.s-1) %/% k), use.names = FALSE)]
}
```

Comment: If the numbers do repeat, apply this function to `seq_along(x)` and use the output to index `x` with `[`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, brilliant! I'll make the edit (if you don't beat me to it).

Comment: Looks like a good solution. Could @Arun please explain the seq_along output mentioned by Matthew

Comment: If `x` is from 1 to n, then the result is a permuted vector, but it's also the corresponding permuted index. So, if your actual `x` is repeating, we can create a new vector 1:n and then create this permuted index that can be used to index `x`. Does this help?

Comment: I don't think you need `match`. You can do `unlist(split(x[y], (y-1) %/% k), use.names = FALSE)`. Also, things should be faster if `k <- 3L` (an integer).

Comment: @flodel, yes indeed, thank you. I've added your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 8):

Arun didn't like how inefficient my other answer was, so here's something very fast just for him ;)

It requires just one call each to `runif()` and `order()`, and doesn't use `sample()` at all.

```
x <- 1:100
k <- 3
n <- length(x)

x[order(rep(seq_len(ceiling(n/k)), each=k, length.out=n) + runif(n))]
#  [1]   3   1   2   6   5   4   8   9   7  11  12  10  13  14  15  18  16  17
# [19]  20  19  21  23  22  24  27  25  26  29  28  30  33  31  32  36  34  35
# [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  47  48  46  51  49  50  52  54  53
# [55]  55  57  56  58  60  59  62  63  61  66  64  65  68  67  69  71  70  72
# [73]  75  74  73  76  77  78  81  80  79  84  82  83  86  85  87  89  88  90
# [91]  93  92  91  94  96  95  97  98  99 100
```

Answer (score 6):

For the record, the **boot** package (shipped with base R) includes a function `permutation.array()` that is used for just this purpose:

```
x <- 1:100
k <- 3
ii <- boot:::permutation.array(n = length(x), 
                               R = 2, 
                               strata = (seq_along(x) - 1) %/% k)[1,]
x[ii]
#   [1]   2   1   3   6   5   4   9   7   8  12  11  10  15  13  14  16  18  17
#  [19]  21  19  20  23  22  24  26  27  25  28  29  30  33  31  32  36  35  34
#  [37]  38  39  37  41  40  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  51  50  49  53  52  54
#  [55]  57  55  56  59  60  58  63  61  62  65  66  64  67  69  68  72  71  70
#  [73]  75  73  74  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  86  87  85  89  88  90
#  [91]  93  91  92  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: Nice solution. But I'd like to point out that this function is inefficient (at least for this task). They use a `table` on `strata`. This'll be time-consuming as x is large and has lot of unique entries. They internally use a function `rperm` on each `group` where `rperm` is `sample0(x, length(x))`. In other words, they call `sample` many times as well. Running this function on larger `x` (even 1e3 or 1e4, for example) clearly shows the difference.

Comment: @Arun -- OK. I posted another answer, which is fast, and calls `sample()` **zero** times, which I think you'll appreciate. I think it's currently the best answer here. What do you think?

Comment: Brilliant! Yes indeed, that's the fastest and the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will drop elements at the end (with a warning):

```
locality <- 3
x <- 1:100
c(apply(matrix(x, nrow=locality, ncol=length(x) %/% locality), 2, sample))
## [1]  1  2  3  4  6  5  8  9  7 12 10 11 13 15 14 16 18 17 19 20 21 22 24 23 26 25 27 28 30 29 32 33 31 35 34 36 38 39 37
## [40] 42 40 41 43 44 45 47 48 46 51 49 50 54 52 53 55 57 56 58 59 60 62 61 63 64 65 66 67 69 68 71 72 70 74 75 73 78 77 76
## [79] 80 81 79 83 82 84 87 85 86 88 89 90 92 93 91 96 94 95 99 98 97
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v <- 1:16

scramble <- function(vec,n) {
  res <- tapply(vec,(seq_along(vec)+n-1)%/%n,
                FUN=function(x) x[sample.int(length(x), size=length(x))])
  unname(unlist(res))
}

set.seed(42)
scramble(v,3)
#[1]  3  2  1  6  5  4  9  7  8 12 10 11 15 13 14 16

scramble(v,4)
#[1]  2  3  1  4  5  8  6  7 10 12  9 11 14 15 16 13
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Matthew's approach way better but here was the way I did the problem:

```
x <- 1:100
fact <- 3

y <- ceiling(length(x)/fact)

unlist(lapply(split(x, rep(1:y, each =fact)[1:length(x)]), function(x){
    if (length(x)==1) return(x)
    sample(x)
}), use.names = FALSE)

##   [1]   3   1   2   6   4   5   8   9   7  11  10  12  13  15  14  17  16  18
##  [19]  20  21  19  24  23  22  26  27  25  29  30  28  31  32  33  35  34  36
##  [37]  39  37  38  41  42  40  45  43  44  47  46  48  51  49  50  52  53  54
##  [55]  57  56  55  59  60  58  63  62  61  64  66  65  67  68  69  70  71  72
##  [73]  75  73  74  77  76  78  80  79  81  82  84  83  85  86  87  90  89  88
##  [91]  92  91  93  96  94  95  98  99  97 100
```